# For... To VBA loop is not ending?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following loop written,

```
For X = 1 To N
    Rng.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 670).Copy
    Rng.Offset(1, -3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next X
i = i + N
```

Which is supposed to start on a row (defined by i), and make new rows based on what N is. If N is equal to 20, I want this code to make 20 copies, then move onto the next row. However, on row 1, N = 3, and copy/pasting just seems to happen over and over. Any suggestions?

For context, the entire the code is as follows:

```
Sub NuPubPrepare()

    Dim i As Long, k As Long, N As Long, Entry As Range, Rng As Range

    i = 2
    While i <= 400
        Set Entry = Range("K" & i)
        For k = Columns("K").Column To Columns("GB").Column Step 5
            Set Entry = Union(Entry, Cells(i, k))
        Next k
        Set Rng = Range("D" & i)
        N = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Entry)

        If N = 1 Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            For X = 1 To N
                Rng.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 670).Copy
                Rng.Offset(1, -3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Next X
            i = i + N 

        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

So N will count the number of cells with data in them across a wide range (Every 5 cells from Ki to GBi), and I'm trying to make the script insert new lines based on this number.

Comment: The code here looks entirely fine. Is this inside a trigger? What does the rest of the function do? I could imagine a trigger on added rows being a reason for this seeming infinite.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the conformation. I'll edit in the rest of the code now.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me `N` becomes zero before `i` reaches 400.

Comment: @GSerg, I thought that was the case, too, but I added the line `Rng.Value = N` before the `If...` line, and it prints the correct numbers into the range Rng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do as you ask.

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("1:1")
    For i = 1 To 5
        rng.Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        rng.Copy
        rng.Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this method of copy and pasting didn't lead to the infinite loop. Thanks!